# How to add current hostname as a global tag in InfluxDB's Telegraf?

Tags: influxdb, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin

Telegraf can be configured to add [global tags](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/CONFIGURATION.md#global-tags) to all measurements. They can [reference environment variables](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/CONFIGURATION.md#environment-variables), but I couldn't find if or how they can reference [agent defaults](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/CONFIGURATION.md#agent), which configures and provides `hostname` to plugins.

I imagine something like

```ini
[global_tags]
  host = ...  # value from [agent].hostname, either configured or the default `os.Hostname()`
```